# Lync Server 2010 with Hosted VoIP PBX

Tags: voip, sip, pbx, lync

We just deployed Lync Server 2010 in our organization and it is working great so far.

The next step for us is to enable enterprise voice so that we can replace our telephones with service that is handled 100% by Lync. This is where I am at a loss.

I have a fully deployed Standard Edition Lync server and a hosted VoIP PBX provider with VoIP handsets. I would like to get rid of the handsets and have my company's phone service be handled by Lync client (e.g. someone calls my work number, and Lync rings instead of my old handset that is set up with the PBX)

I am new to deploying these types of features. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Considering Lync 2010 only has 14 months of mainstream support left why not go with 2013?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be totally PBX-less and "pure Lync to PSTN" then you want a SIP Trunk which is like a hosted PBX over Internet.  [Here's your options for connecting to PSTN (public swtiched telephone network](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425749.aspx) and the partner I've used is [IntelePeer](http://www.intelepeer.com/SIPTrunking) which can give you a 30-day free trial of a few phone numbers to test with.  They are certified on Lync and can help you configure it.  On your end you need to enable the Lync Mediation Role which acts as a SIP Router for any calls to/from the SIP trunking provider.  There are some firewall rules, and settings you need to setup obviously but that should get you started.  It's not as easy as installing Skype, but once it works it's an awesome replacement for legacy PBX :).  Might also want to read the [Voice Deployment Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=af7cced8-e110-434e-97de-300b8a064e16).

Other option is to keep PBX and get a gateway that supports your PBX and Lync and sits between them, also discussed at the first link above.

Comment: Thanks I'll chew on that and get back to you. If i decide to go "pure Lync to PSTN", do I need to have PSTN lines put down or will the sip trunking peer take care of that?

Comment: it's pure VoIP.  No telco stuff onsite other then servers and Internet.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to note that Lync cannot use a typical username/pass sip register from an online provider like callcentric or ace innovative. For those you would either have to put a Asterisk (unsupported by Microsoft but works - I do warn you that call centric has a interesting way of presenting DID's) box in-between (or possibly an audiocodec's box) or use a certified direct sip provider like IntelePeer.

One thing you do have to be careful up when doing enterprise voice is 911 capabilities of remote workers. Right now there is support by 911 Enable for large deployments, but I have not seen anything yet for the small-medium business for the 10-200 size deployments.

Comment: Quite a few SIP providers support E911 which pass extra information per DID. Assuming your remote works get their own DID, you can get it going that way. In our setup, we map the users desk phone to their E911, and their home phone sends out the same callerid. The other users are handled by an in-between service which answers the called before 911 one gets it. It however is something like 50USD per call.

Comment: May I ask which service you are using for 911 in-between? Because I have not seen many on the small business side.

Comment: We have service from Broadvox in the US.